# MySQL complex query

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have the following tables defined in MySQL:

```
create table car (
   brand int
   car-color int
   car-price int
   car-number int auto_increment;
   primary key (bradn, car-color);
   UNIQUE(car-number) ;
);

create table concurrent (
   person-id int;
   car-number int;

   primary key (person-id, car-number);
   foreign key (person-id) references person(id);
   foreign key (car-number) references car(car-number);
);

create table value-placed (
   person-id int;
   car-number int;
   value int;
   primary key (person-id, car-number, value);
   foreign key (person-id, car-number) references concurrent (person-id, car-number);
);
```

I know the code is not well written, it's just to get an idea.

Basically, we have Cars which have a base price (car-price), people can sign them selves as concurrents to buy a car, and people can register values for the competition for the cars they are in. At the end of X days, the person with the highest value on a car wins the car.

Now, the query i want is:

- What is the car with the highest ratio (highest value put among all the concurrents for that car) / (base price)

I can explain better: i want to take, for each car, the highest price a person has placed in it. So say, if person A places 500 on car 1 and person B places 100 on car 2, i want to take the value 500 and divide it by the car 1 base price.

I need to do this for every car and return the highest ratio.

How can i do this?

Comment: What stops you from completing this assignment?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: For the love of humanity, don't include '-' in table/column idenitifers!!!

Comment: Your code is a syntactic mess. Have you even looked at [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)?

Comment: I know the code is a mess. This is NOT my code, its just a mental representation of the tables. I have tried to do the query but so far i can only create a query to get the highest value put by all the persons in a car

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery to compute the maximum value per car, then join the subquery result to the table carrying the car price per car (i.e. `car`).  Each row of the joined result then has the price and the maximum value, from which you can compute (and order by) the ratio.  If you only want the highest ratio, then in MySQL (and many other DBMSs) you can limit the results returned to just that row.

Overall, you might have something like this:

```
SELECT
  car.car_number, (max_value.value / car.car_price) AS ratio
FROM
  car
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      car_number,
      MAX(value) AS value
    FROM
      value_placed
    GROUP BY
      car_number
  ) max_value
    ON car.car_number = max_value.car_number
ORDER BY ratio DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this :

```
select c.carnumber, max(vp.value/c.carprice) ratio
from car c
join valueplaced vp on vp.carnumber = c.carnumber
group by c.carnumber
order by ratio desc;
```

[SQL Fiddle to show results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee416a/4/0)